# Insert into Google Merchant data feed using Content API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, httpclient

I'm trying to insert some data into my merchant account data feed using the Content API. Using the code below, I've been given a "POST requests require a Content-length header. That’s all we know." error, but I've set the content length, so I'm really confused.

One theory I have is that it doesn't know where to put these requests, under my merchant account ID, I have two data feeds, and I'm not sure how to set it to enter into a given data feed.

The XML is stolen from here: https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/batch-operations

```
@feed = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"
        xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
        xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch">

    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:sc="http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009"
        xmlns:scp="http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009/products"
        xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
        <batch:operation type="INSERT"/>
        <title>Switch 1</title>
        <content type="text">A new item available...</content>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.example.com/sku123"/>
        <sc:id>SKU123</sc:id>
        <sc:content_language>en</sc:content_language>
        <sc:target_country>US</sc:target_country>
        <scp:google_product_category>Electronics  &gt; Networking  &gt; Hubs  &amp;
        Switches</scp:google_product_category>
        <scp:condition>new</scp:condition>
        <scp:price unit="USD">25</scp:price>
        <scp:availability>in stock</scp:availability>
    </entry>


    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sc="http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009"
    xmlns:scp="http://schemas.google.com/structuredcontent/2009/products"
    xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
      <batch:operation type="INSERT"/>
      <title>Switch 2</title>
      <content type="text">Another item available...</content>
      <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.example.com/sku124"/>
      <sc:id>SKU124</sc:id>
      <sc:content_language>en</sc:content_language>
      <sc:target_country>US</sc:target_country>
      <scp:google_product_category>Electronics  &gt; Networking  &gt; Hubs  &amp;
    Switches</scp:google_product_category>
      <scp:condition>new</scp:condition>
      <scp:price unit="USD">50</scp:price>
      <scp:availability>in stock</scp:availability>
     </entry>

    </feed>'


    http = HTTPClient.new
    @output = http.post('https://content.googleapis.com/content/v1/<myMerchantID>/items/products/schema/batch', {},"content"=> @feed, "Content-length"=>@feed.length.to_s, "GData-Version"=> "1", "Authorization" => "AuthSub token=myToken", "Content-Type"=> "application/atom+xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you Authenticating prior to your post?

https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/getting-started/authentication